# Несколько баз данных Symfony 3

Tags: php, база-данных, symfony, symfony3

Symfony 3. Проект использует основную базу данных. Есть задача: взять данные из основной базы, обработать и положить в несколько других БД. Как сконфигурировать приложение, чтобы можно было оперативно переключаться между разными базами данных?

Comment: предполагаю, что используется doctrine. если так, то используйте разные connections и вешайте на них соответсвенные entity_manager: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Answer (score 3):

Нужно использовать разные EntityManager-ы. Их настройка и пример использования описаны в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/613665/208074) к вопросу «Подключение к БД в контроллере Symfony 3».